# How to send an email using mailx so that From and To appear correctly in the email?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, mailx

I need to send an email from my Ubuntu 12.04 machine. I am using `mailx` command to do that. Below is the command I am using which works fine.

```
echo "Test server started at `date +"%F %T"` on `hostname -f`" | mailx -r "abc@host.com" -s "Test Email" "pqr@host.com"
```

But when I get an email, I see in my `From` section as `david@machineA.host.com` and in my `To` section, I can see `abc@host.com` and `pqr@host.com`.

Why not it is showing `abc@host.com` in my From and only `pqr@host.com` in To once I get an email.

In general what I am trying to do is - I need to send an email from `abc@host.com` to `pqr@host.com` so that in From section I should see `abc@host.com` and in To section I should see `pqr@host.com` in my email instead of my machine name in the From section.

It looks to me that we need to change something while installing `mailutils`? I installed it using `sudo apt-get install mailutils`

How to send an email using mailx so that From and To appear correctly in the email?

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 -

```
david@machineA:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
Release:        12.04
Codename:       precise
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `mailutils` doesn't support the `-r` option. Replace it with the heirloom-mailx package which does support the -r option (or use sendmail -r [or -f]).

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/mail.1.html

```
 -p, -r, --print, --read
              print all mail to standard output
```

Install:

> sudo apt-get install heirloom-mailx

Comment: Thanks for the help again. How can I install `heirloom-mailx` in Ubuntu 12.04. Is there any way to do that easily?

Comment: @david, no problem. I updated my post, that should work.